# foreign key constraints forbiding cascading delete

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

I have teams that can be assigned team members and people.  The team table and person tables already exist and can't be touched, I'm creating join tables to assign team members and team leads.

I have one key constraint, a team lead must be a team member, and as long as someone is assigned as a team lead it should be impossible to remove them as a team member.

My sql looks something like this (translating from a more complex table, forgive me if I mistyped my example since I'm writing it by hand)

```
CREATE TABLE TEAM_MEMBERS (id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  teamId BIGINT NOT NULL,
  personId BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY (teamId),
  KEY (personId)

  CONSTRAINT fk_team FOREIGN KEY (teamId) REFERENCES TEAM(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE TEAM_LEAD (id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  teamId BIGINT NOT NULL,
  personId BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY (teamId),
  KEY (personId),
  CONSTRAINT fk_team_u FOREIGN KEY (teamId) REFERENCES TEAM (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_child FOREIGN KEY (teamId, personId) REFERENCES TEAM_MEMBERS(teamId, personId)) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

This does not work.  When a team is removed I get a constraint violation, because it cascades the delete to team_members first, attempts to delete that, and discovers that team_lead is blocking it.

My question, is there an easy way express some sort of order of operations here, to make sql understand that it should remove the team-lead first, or otherwise understand that it is not a constraint violation if it cascades the deletes entirely?

I realize one solution would be to make teamLead a boolean on team_members rather then a separate join table.  For various reasons I would prefer not to do this, but it can be done if there is not another cleaner solution.

Were using PostgreSQL on server, H2 for our testing, though we would prefer not to be tied in to a DB if possible.

Comment: "*though we would prefer not to be tied in to a DB if possible*" - do you create your web applications in a way that you are not tied to a web-framework? Or your GUI/Desktop applications so that you are not tied to a GUI framework? Or your application itself so that it is not tied to a specific programming language?

Comment: Why not just have a boolean column on team_members called IsTeamLead? I don't get why you need a separate team_lead table.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't simply moved the `fk_child` constraint to `TEAM_MEMBERS` and reversed it?  `CONSTRAINT fk_parent FOREIGN KEY (teamId, personId) REFERENCES TEAM_LEAD(teamId, personId)) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT;` or am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL constraint should not be here:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_child FOREIGN KEY (teamId, personId) REFERENCES TEAM_MEMBERS(teamId, personId)) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Your data model seems wrong: a team leader should not have a foreign key pointing to team members, but to a team only.

Could you please post the complete schema so we could provide a more complete answer?

Comment: The full schema is rather...complex.  I simplified it because It would be hard to follow and has some propitiatory things in it.  However, other then our 'teams' being more like existing situations that people can be assigned to resolve/work on (and thus existing independent of rather any person or lead is assigned) I think the description describes all the stuff relevant to this question.  Our teams and people exist, I need to assign multiple people to address the 'team' and make one a leader.  Due to our abstraction layer having a Boolean on the team_members to represent the leader is awkwar

Comment: but that line was clearly wrong. I agree the boolean is a bad idea. You need to have an extra table to handle the joint between team members and team, but not between team members and team lead.

Comment: another strange thing: when a team disband, you should not propagate deletion to team members. they should remain in the db, but their former role in the team is gone. they might still have roles in another team.

Comment: people is it's own table, separate from team members (which is just a join table), so we can cascade a delete to team members without removing the people themselves.

Comment: so team_members being a many to many join table, ```id``` is not needed as a primary key (it seems to be just a rowid), ```(teamId,personId)``` is the primary key, therefore a reference is missing in this table. As said, the data model looks wrong. If you cannot remove the confidential part, it'll be hard to fix

Comment: " Due to our abstraction layer having a Boolean on the team_members to represent the leader is awkwar" - The design should start with the data model, not abstraction layer, otherwise, you end up with the types of problems you're seeing. As already pointed out, there's no good reason to have team_lead as a separate table, because you can store that information in the team_members table. My advice is to get the data model right, because nothing else matters if you fail there. Doing hacks with the data model to "make it work" with your abstraction layer will have bad results.

Comment: By the way it seems there could be more than one leader per team from text above. I retract my statement on boolean. But I don't see how to preserve his specific constraint.

Comment: @Christian MICHON - The boolean would still work fine in that case, there's no need to retract your statement. IsTeamLead would be true for each team member who is a lead for that particular team. To prevent deleting members that are team leads, you could do that via a trigger if desired.